# In general, what is the quickest path through the jungle?

Tags: league-of-legends

Has anyone figured out the fastest jungle path in league of legends to get to every jungle monster? Including the enemies starting in your home base.

Assume no items, abilities or summoners to help you move faster just base movement speed and a walk around the jungles to every camp including the crab. I'm just looking for the fastest route by walking.

Comment: Do you mean just by walking?  There are some champs that have built in dashes that can make moving through the jungle much faster (by being able to go over/under/through walls).  The fastest  path for a champ with such dashes will be different than the path for a champ without them.  Some dashes are larger than others, which means some champs can jump a wall that another champ wouldn't be able too.  Also, is using summoner spells allowed?

Comment: Since the river mobs are moving, there's not one but a good deal of "faster" runs. Does the routes would need to avoid detection from the enemy team or not? Dashes, spells as mentioned by GeneralMike?

Comment: You say no movespeed items, but do you mean with just machete or full build? Either way this sounds like less of a "practical" question and more of a "dude, what would happen" question.

Comment: @AverageUnknown why is not "practical"? I'm looking for a optimal route that is the fastest that could be usable by any champion.

Comment: I mean "practical" in the sense that you're assuming a lot by asking about quickest clear--namely that nobody is going to interfere and nobody else is going to be farming the jungle. Both of these things are untrue if the enemy team has a jungler, which is basically mandatory these days.

Comment: @AverageUnknown Not so much about clear more the time it takes to travel from one camp to the next, what if I see their jungler top and I know I can get to their blue, wolves, gromp before he gets back while he is traveling his top jungle?

Comment: It still seems like an odd question for the application you're suggesting. You could just ask which champion has the quickest clear--but that still depends on any number of factors from the time elapsed to the champion's items to how fed they are. Most jungle capable champs have similar clear speed until carry junglers start getting their end-game builds.

Comment: If you want movement speed, I'd say Master Yi. His abilities allow him to clear the jungle quite fast. I think he does have the fastest clear time in the game if used properly.

Comment: How does the LoL movement system work? I think your character goes to the destination following the fastest path anyway.

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat: In LoL, there are several "camps" where neutral monsters spawn that can be killed for gold, xp, and temporary special abilities.  When the OP is asking about the fastest path through the jungle, he is implying that he wants to kill all the monsters to collect the gold and buffs.  Due to the location of the camps relative to one another and the nature of the buffs, simply right-clicking and letting the autopathing take you from one camp to the next is not necessarily the fastest way through.

Comment: @GeneralMike Where is the value in that? There is no general path that any champion can take as each champion is different. Since each champion differs, it makes sense to just go left to right or right to left since there is no base line champion used in this example.

Comment: Wraiths>Wolves?Blue>Wraiths?Red/Golems>Red/Golems
from the LoL official forums.

Answer (score 3):

Each champion has a different clear speed and strength in the jungle. There is no defined jungle path, and with each game, the jungle path should change to avoid following predictable jungle patterns which the enemy jungler can read, utilize and abuse.

For better information on which paths fit which jungler(champion), visit:
https://www.youtube.com/user/stonewall008

Stonewall generally has updated videos on new jungle paths, decision points and best clear path.

Personal preference: 
Gromp->Blue->Wraiths->Red->Krugs->Wolves->Back.

Comment: Gromp->Blue->wolves->wraiths->red->Krugs

Comment: For clear speed, it's the other way around with AD champions that proc red buff. Finishing off with scuttler on both routes.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest (∴fastest) path starting from base is to first go to Golems, this is closer as the crow flies than Gromp and you also do not need to deviate as much from that straight path.

From Gromp go to red and then wraiths, then go to scuttler. However if you want to optimize it completely you should have a ward in the river so that you know where the scuttler is, if it's all the way near bot (or top depending on which side you're on) after you get to wraiths you should go to wolves next and then gromp then blue then scuttle then scuttle.

If it's closer though, then from wraiths go to the scuttler, now from here go to the other scuttler then blue -> gromp -> wolves.

However there are a lot more than you should consider when choosing a jungle path then just the shortest distance. Clearing time for instance changes drastically depending on your champion and/or items, which will mean that certain routes might be better.

Also to consider is the respawn time, so your first clear may be faster, but your second clear might be slower for instance. Usually you'll want to make sure you get the buffs sooner so that they respawn sooner giving you more gold sooner, for this reason some people choose to go red -> blue. Which gives you a lot of gold (and two buffs) for less work, meaning you can gank with the buffs that make you stronger.

Also you could time when you take red in order to give you the health boost when you need it more so that you can continue jungling for longer which may mean you don't have to go back before you have enough money for that next item.